# How to know which variables are more important in a process?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, importance

I have a process with 15 effective variables. I could record 9 variables to study its effect on process.
I am looking for an appropriate factor to estimate the value of effectiveness of each factor. I believe p-values, standardized coefficients, partial correlation and partial $R^2$ are the potential solutions in this regard.

Which one is more useful in informing the degree of effectiveness of each variable on scale of 0 to 100?

Comment: Could you say a little more about the details of your context? Is it time series data? are the predictor variables experimentally manipulated or just observed? What is the aim of your analysis: control, prediction, something else?

Answer (score -1):

I assume from the your phrasing "process" that this is time series data. If so with 15 possible supporting variables I guess you want to select the best 9 to use as predictors for some output series. After taking into account any unspecified deterministic structure such as pulses,level shifts,seasonal pulses and/or local time trends you could form a Transfer Function (ARMAX MODEL). After validating that the parameters haven't changed over time and the variance of the errors is constant or at a minimum rendering both of these two assumptions to be true via appropriate Gaussian fixup strategies you might have a useful model. Since you didn't design/ortogonalize the study but simply observed , you can't unambiguosly state how much variability is explained by each input or refer to each input separately as having any partial effect. Collectively the coeffficients ( including any needed lags ) for any and all of the input series can be said to best predict the output series.